# After upgrading to rails 4.1, acts-as-taggable-on is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have upgraded my rails version of one my app to 4.1.0. While upgrading I have upgraded all gems from Gemfile, which upgraded acts-as-taggable-on to 3.1.1 too.

but after upgrade, when I tried to add tags on respective object, it is failing with following error.

```
  post = Post.last
  post.tag_list = "development"
  post.save
```

> ERROR:  column "taggings_count" does not exist

details error is here:

```
SQL (0.9ms)  UPDATE "tags" SET "taggings_count" = COALESCE("taggings_count", 0) - 1 WHERE "tags"."id" = 3146
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "taggings_count" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "tags" SET "taggings_count" = COALESCE("taggings_coun...
                                                      ^
: UPDATE "tags" SET "taggings_count" = COALESCE("taggings_count", 0) - 1 WHERE "tags"."id" = 3146
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "taggings_count" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "tags" SET "taggings_count" = COALESCE("taggings_coun...
                                                      ^
: UPDATE "tags" SET "taggings_count" = COALESCE("taggings_count", 0) - 1 WHERE "tags"."id" = 3146
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

just we have to do,

> rake acts_as_taggable_on_engine:install:migrations

Since acts-as-taggable-on has added new migrations.

Comment: I got a problem on Duplicate entry ... for key 'index_tags_on_name': CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_tags_on_name`  ON `tags` (`name`). don't know if there is something to understand right here

Comment: In the first migration this generates,  remove the first line creating the index_tags_on_name (I'd copy/paste, but I already removed it).